# ¿como identificar tablas sin columna identity en sql server?

Tags: sql

Necesito controlar las bases SQL (varias tablas) las cuales deben poseer Identificadores Identity en la columna 'Id' que todas poseen. 
Lo más aproximado que llegué a sido a esto:

```
SELECT
distinct TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS,
sys.Objects so
WHERE
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
and so.Type = 'U' And so.name = 'Id'
ORDER BY
TABLE_NAME
```

Esta consulta solo me da las tablas y columnas que poseen Identity, y como son varias bases de 180 tablas cada una, resulta engorroso buscarlas.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Pero ya lo resolviste! todas las tablas (que ya lo tenes en tu select), not in este select!

Answer (score 3):

La siguiente consulta te puede ayudar a conocer el nombre de la tabla y si tiene campo de tipo `IDENTITY`. Simplemente es hacer `JOIN` a la definición de tablas y columnas con respecto al campo llave `object_id`:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.is_identity = 1
ORDER BY t.name
```

Para listar con un solo *query* todos los campos que son `IDENTITY` de todas las bases de datos quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);

SET @sql = N'select cast(''master'' as sysname) as db_name, t.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI Tabla, c.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI Columna, c.is_identity from master.sys.tables t INNER JOIN master.sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE c.is_identity = 1';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' union all select ' + quotename(name, '''') + ', t.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, c.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI object_id, c.is_identity from ' + quotename(name) + N'.sys.tables t INNER JOIN ' + quotename(name) + '.sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE c.is_identity = 1'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 1
    AND STATE = 0
    AND user_access = 0
    AND name NOT IN (
        'tempdb'
        ,'model'
        ,'msdb'
        )

--PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Usted es un capo :D

Comment: @fredyfx muchas cosas las he aprendido de usted, maestro :D

Comment: gracias hermano, al igual que Jhony (yo), de usted :D #ElevamosElCosmos #ConTodoElPower2.0!!!

Answer (score 0):

Crea la función y luego usa este SP.

En el hay código para deducir el nombre del campo IDENTIDAD, aunque la función resetea el valor acorde al MAX.

```sql
-- ********************* CREAR ESTA FUNCIÓN PRIMERO *******************************
/*
create function  dbo.FN_EsIdentidad(@Tabla nvarchar(100), @Campo nvarchar(100))
    returns int
    as
    begin
        return columnproperty ( object_id ( @Tabla  ), @Campo , 'IsIdentity')
    end 
GO
************************************************************************************
*/

alter PROCEDURE RESEED(@Tabla nvarchar(100))as
declare @CampoIdentidad nvarchar(100)
    SELECT @CampoIdentidad  = Column_Name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        where dbo.FN_EsIdentidad(Table_Name, Column_name) = 1 
        and Table_Name=@Tabla
declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
declare @OutPutNum int
set @Sql = 'Select MAX(' + @CampoIdentidad + ') From ' + @Tabla
--select @CampoIdentidad
set @sql = 'Select @ValorOut=max(' + @CampoIdentidad + ') From ' + @Tabla 
declare @ParamDefinition nvarchar(max)
SET @ParamDefinition = '@ValorOut int OUTPUT'
EXECUTE sp_executesql  
    @SQL 
    ,@ParamDefinition  
    ,@ValorOut = @OutPutNum OUTPUT;  
DBCC CHECKIDENT (@Tabla, RESEED, @OutputNum)

go

RESEED 'gas_botellas'
```